# Patch Removal Keeps Failing Due To Incorrect MSI Retrieval

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, patch

I have a package which you can install using an MSI. The installation log of this package shows the following properties when executing the msiexec command:

```
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\Windows\Installer\2bb7bb.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = C:\temp\DDS_COM_ETMS_Win-2008-64_01-04-01_install_09\ElektronTMS.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 2
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = D:\
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\temp\DDS_COM_ETMS_Win-2008-64_01-04-01_install_09\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8}
```

Now, I installed a patch for this package, and I try and do the uninstall/fallback of the patch but I immediately see it is using the wrong package (a cached copy of the original package msi is in C:\Windows\Installer\ and it is 2bb7bb.msi).

```
=== Verbose logging started: 18/12/2015  14:58:05  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (04:A8) [14:58:05:290]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (04:A8) [14:58:05:290]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (04:A8) [14:58:05:290]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (04:A8) [14:58:05:290]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (04:A8) [14:58:05:290]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (04:A8) [14:58:05:526]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (04:A8) [14:58:05:526]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (04:A8) [14:58:05:536]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (08:E0) [14:58:05:553]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction {7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8}
MSI (s) (08:E0) [14:58:05:553]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:555]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:555]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:555]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:556]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:578]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:579]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:579]: Original package ==> C:\Windows\Installer\2bb7c2.msi
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:579]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\2bb7c2.msi
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:580]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall Flags override found.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:580]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall VersionNT override found.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:580]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall ServicePackLevel override found.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:589]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8}'.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:601]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:612]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:05:625]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\fb55f.msp'.
```

This causes problems down the line...

```
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: Resolving source.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: User policy value 'DisableMedia' is 0
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownMedia' is 0
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Media enabled only if package is safe.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Looking for sourcelist for product {7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8}
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Adding {7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8}; to potential sourcelist list (pcode;disk;relpath).
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Now checking product {7F03FFFD-D865-41D1-B4B5-B787F52336D8}
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Media is enabled for product.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Attempting to use LastUsedSource from source list.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Trying source C:\temp\DDS_COM_ETMS_Win-2008-64_01-04-01_install_09\.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\temp\DDS_COM_ETMS_Win-2008-64_01-04-01_install_09\ElektronTMS.msi 3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to missing/inaccessible package.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: ElektronTMS.msi 
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing net source list.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: ElektronTMS.msi 
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:626]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing media source list.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: Note: 1: 2203 2:  3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to missing/inaccessible package.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: ElektronTMS.msi 
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing URL source list.
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\URL 3: 2 
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: ElektronTMS.msi 
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: Note: 1: 1706 2:  3: ElektronTMS.msi 
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: SOURCEMGMT: Failed to resolve source
MSI (s) (08:EC) [14:58:07:627]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
```

Does anyone know why it is using a different C:\Windows\Installer\XXX.msi file? It should be using the original file and then using that to reinstall the original DLLs but for some reason it's using 2bb7c2.msi instead of 2bb7bb.msi (doesn't exist) but the 2bb7c2.msi is the original patch and 2bb7bb.msi which have been the original package MSI.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that you installed from a temp location, and patch uninstall requires access to the original MSI to restore the previous files. In the absence of anything else that shows an actual bug, it's no more complicated than that. It wants the original MSI file, with the required PackageCode, ProductCode etc, and it appears to be either missing, or a mismatch, or Windows has lost the privileges to access that file if in fact it is there.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that when you use MSI patch, it changes original msi file. After that this msi file will install product, that alreay has patch changes. And, what more important in your case, remove only full patched product too.

If you want to remove update, obtained with patch, but retain original product, you should go to Windows Update -> View Update Journal and then click to Installed Updates (My version of Windows is not English, but it should be named something like this). In this section you may find your update. Clicking "Remove" on it will remove patch.

Comment: I can't remove the update. That's what it is trying to do. It asks to find the original product's MSI.

Comment: @sushi7777, do you see your patch in "Installed Updates" screen?